# Is it possible to "win" the port-a-diner pie?

Tags: fallout-4

In a few locations I've found what appears to be a claw-game of sorts. It reaches down and attempts to pick up a plate of pie, but fails every time I've tried at least. The claw does move above a little conveyor belt where you would expect it drop off your prize, and there's even a slot to claim it at the end.

But my question is, can you actually "win" that piece of pie? Or will you lose every time?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I have had it work actually.. My first try so every attempt hereafter has been a disappointment.. It provided me with a 'Perfectly Preserved Pie' item that I crashed shortly after getting so do not know its stats. I do not know what affects the chance of getting it or not, I have pretty high Luck (9) so that may have helped.

If you don't want to take my word for it you can see a video of it being done here:

Comment: And here I was, hoping the cake really was a lie.

Comment: as if Fallout 4 didn't contain enough things for me to keep doing repeatedly... -.-

Answer (score 11):

**Yes, you can win it**, although it seems to be as random as the programmed claw machines you play to win toys actually are.  I won it after maybe clicking a machine twenty times - took it back to Diamond City and wanted to put it on my coffee table, but when I dropped it, it disappeared.  So, be careful about not doing that.  Stats on it are nothing special, but the feeling of winning it is stupidly good.
[image: Perfectly Preserved Pie]

Answer (score 1):

I've done some testing and it looks like winning the pie is possible with the likelihood bound to your luck skill. I tested this by using console commands on two different saves, one with luck value set to 1 and one with luck value set to 99999. With the 99999 luck I would win on first try, whereas with luck set to 1 I failed ten times.

Answer (score -1):

I had success after only 8 attempts.

It is possible but you have to have luck. It has nothing to do with the Luck property.

Answer (score -2):

I've won this 10 times already. It's not impossible. I can show you a picture of me getting the pie and just having it in my inventory. I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with having luck at 10.

Comment: Not impossible just hard.